# Effective resistance of weighted bipartite graph

Tags: graph-theory, random-walk, bipartite-graphs, graph-laplacian

### Question:

Let $K_{m,n}$ be a **weighted** complete bipartite graph with weights $w_{ij}$ for each edge $(i,j)$.
What is the effective resistance $R_{i,j}$ between any two nodes of the graph? I am interested in using its expression to compute the pseudoinverse of the graph Laplacian.

---

#### Some context:

A possible starting point may be [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2759328/graph-theory-question-about-electrical-networks-on-bipartite-graphs), which I would like to extend to the weighted graph case. I believe (I may be completely off track) that following the answer (3rd solution) from [@Misha Lavrov](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/383078/misha-lavrov) it is possible to find the resistance between any two points belonging to a different partition of the graph. My attempt is as follows.

Let any edge $(i,j)$ of the graph have weight $w_{ij}$, i.e. resistance $r_{ij} := 1/w_{ij}$. Let $s_i := \sum_j{w_{ij}}$ for each node $i$. We can define a random walk on the edges of the graph using the transition matrix $P_{ij} := \frac{w_{ij}}{s_{i}}$ (note that even if the weight metrix is symmetric in general $P_{ij} \neq P_{ji}$). Then the effective resistance then can be measured as the probability that a random walk starting at $u$ ends up at $v$ by taking the edge $uv$, that should be:

$$
R_{u,v} := P_{uv} + (1-P_{uv})P_{vu}
$$

with the interpretation: $P_{uv}$  ''$=$'' probability of going from $u$ to $v$ when doing the first step $+$ $(1-P_{uv})$ ''$=$'' probability of jumping to another node as the first step, and then $P_{vu}$ "=" probability of reaching $v$ from $u$ every time we are on the same side of $u$.

#### Here I get stuck:

Is the random walk ''approach'' applicable also for two nodes $u,v$ belonging to the same partition? What is the interpretation of the effective resistance then? (since there is no edge $(u,v)$).
Is there another approach to find $R_{u,v}$ using other tools? (e.g. 1st and 2nd solution of the answer from [@Misha Lavrov](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/383078/misha-lavrov)).

Thanks in advance!